# django forms add aria-label

Tags: django-forms, accessibility, django-crispy-forms

How does one add an aria-label to a django form field?  Is there a standard way?

Can I add it to the field definition or as part of the crispy layout a la `css_class=""`?

I tried adding it via an ```attrs``, e.g.

```
range_start = forms.DateField(
        required=False,
        widget=DateInput(),
        attrs={'aria-label': 'whatevs'}
    )
```

but that gave a TypeError:
`TypeError: Field.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'attrs'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `attrs` to the `widget` rather than the `field`.

```
range_start = forms.DateField(
        required=False,
        widget=DateInput(attrs={'aria-label': 'whatevs'}),
    )
```